Only 16 ttyUSB devices created for 32-port USB to RS-232 device
I recently purchased a Coolgear USB-32COM-RM 32 Port RS-232 USB-to-Serial Adapter connected to a Thinkpad T490s running Mint 21.3. Some lsusb output:
# lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b681 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd ThinkPad T490 Webcam
Bus 001 Device 118: ID 0403:6011 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT4232H Quad HS USB-UART/FIFO IC
Bus 001 Device 117: ID 0403:6011 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT4232H Quad HS USB-UART/FIFO IC
Bus 001 Device 116: ID 0403:6011 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT4232H Quad HS USB-UART/FIFO IC
Bus 001 Device 115: ID 0403:6011 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT4232H Quad HS USB-UART/FIFO IC
Bus 001 Device 114: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 113: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 109: ID 2109:8887 VIA Labs, Inc. 40AN
Bus 001 Device 108: ID 045e:0047 Microsoft Corp. IntelliMouse Explorer 3.0
Bus 001 Device 112: ID 17ef:3083 Lenovo ThinkPad Thunderbolt 3 Dock USB Audio
Bus 001 Device 110: ID 17ef:3081 Lenovo USB2.0 HUB
Bus 001 Device 107: ID 17ef:3080 Lenovo USB2.0 Hub             
Bus 001 Device 106: ID 17ef:3080 Lenovo USB2.0 Hub             
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. Bluetooth 9460/9560 Jefferson Peak (JfP)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

# lsusb -t
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 10000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 480M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 10000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/12p, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 106, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/5p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 107, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 110, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/2p, 480M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 112, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 112, If 0, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 112, If 3, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 112, If 1, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 108, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 5: Dev 109, If 0, Class=, Driver=, 480M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 113, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 114, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
            |__ Port 3: Dev 117, If 2, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=ftdi_sio, 480M
            |__ Port 3: Dev 117, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=ftdi_sio, 480M
            |__ Port 3: Dev 117, If 3, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=ftdi_sio, 480M
            |__ Port 3: Dev 117, If 1, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=ftdi_sio, 480M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 115, If 3, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=ftdi_sio, 480M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 115, If 1, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=ftdi_sio, 480M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 115, If 2, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=ftdi_sio, 480M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 115, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=ftdi_sio, 480M
            |__ Port 4: Dev 118, If 3, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=ftdi_sio, 480M
            |__ Port 4: Dev 118, If 1, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=ftdi_sio, 480M
            |__ Port 4: Dev 118, If 2, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=ftdi_sio, 480M
            |__ Port 4: Dev 118, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=ftdi_sio, 480M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 116, If 2, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=ftdi_sio, 480M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 116, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=ftdi_sio, 480M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 116, If 3, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=ftdi_sio, 480M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 116, If 1, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=ftdi_sio, 480M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 2, If 3, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 2, If 2, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M

Even though this is a 32-port device, I only see 16 /dev/ttyUSB devices:
# ls -ld /dev/ttyUSB*
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188,  0 Dec 12 23:02 /dev/ttyUSB0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188,  1 Dec 12 23:02 /dev/ttyUSB1
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 10 Dec 12 23:02 /dev/ttyUSB10
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 11 Dec 12 23:02 /dev/ttyUSB11
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 12 Dec 12 23:02 /dev/ttyUSB12
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 13 Dec 12 23:02 /dev/ttyUSB13
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 14 Dec 12 23:02 /dev/ttyUSB14
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 15 Dec 12 23:02 /dev/ttyUSB15
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188,  2 Dec 12 23:02 /dev/ttyUSB2
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188,  3 Dec 12 23:02 /dev/ttyUSB3
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188,  4 Dec 12 23:02 /dev/ttyUSB4
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188,  5 Dec 12 23:02 /dev/ttyUSB5
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188,  6 Dec 12 23:02 /dev/ttyUSB6
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188,  7 Dec 12 23:02 /dev/ttyUSB7
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188,  8 Dec 12 23:02 /dev/ttyUSB8
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188,  9 Dec 12 23:02 /dev/ttyUSB9

Why do I only see 16 of the 32 ports?
Update: I removed the case. Looks like the bottom 16 ports are working but not the top 16. I swapped one of the cables from a lower board to the top board and the front lights appeared on the top board rather than the lower board so I might just need to replace the cable. These look like USB cables but the connectors are different. The writing on the cable is "AWM 2725 80C 30V VW-1 E237114 USB(28AWGX1P+28AWGX2C) CABLETECH TECHNOLOGY". Anyone know where I can purchase these USB cables. I reached out to Coolgear as well and am waiting to hear back.


If you look at the output of dmesg are there any USB related errors such as Not enough host controller resources for new device state? According to answers in Can't detect more than 16 USB flash drives there can be hardware limitations.  on the maximum number of supported USB endpoints. Also if you look at the output of lsusb -v and look at the USB serial ports which have been enumerated what value is shown for bNumEndpoints?

dmesg shows no such error. Regarding lsusb -v, I see bNumEndpoints=2 I've been reading about the 16-port limit but don't know if that applies to my case yet. lsusb -v | grep bNumEndpoints shows a total of 82.

Have you tried the device with another computer and e.g. with Windows? You could rule out hardware issues if it works in another system. And if you swapped the cables from the port board side, also try swapping them on the central board too. It still might be that only the first 16 ports work, for whatever reason. It seems a bit unlikely IMO that half if the cables would be broken in such a consistent way.

I tried on a Windows system and only 16 ports were available.
When I swapped the cable, I only swapped the connector on the boards connected to the RJ45 ports, not on the central board. I agree that it's strange for 4 cables to be bad but the lights on the front only come on for half the cables. I think these cables are custom made and not stock.

Those look like some sort of standard 4-pin connector. Maybe they are JST-XH connectors? It would be relatively simple to build your own cables.

@ilkkachu Thanks. I swapped the cables on the central board and that is really where the problem is. Only 4 of the 8 connectors on the central board work so replacing that should fix the problem.
